# Github action reuse env variable inside other

Tags: github, yaml, github-actions

I want to reuse one env variable inside other env variable in YAML Github actions.

I have tried this:

```
name: BUILD AND PUBLISH

on:
  push:
    branches:  "master" 

  pull_request:
    branches:  "master"
    
jobs:
  build:

    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v3
 
    - name: BEFORE Set env variables
      run: echo "NOW=$(date +'%Y.%m.%d-%H.%M.%S')" >> $GITHUB_ENV;
           echo "LINUX_ARM_64_NAME=linux-arm64_${{ env.NOW }}" >> $GITHUB_ENV;

...
```

But the result is:

```
env:
    NOW: 2022.07.06-21.56.48
    LINUX_ARM_64_NAME: linux-arm64_
```

And desired result is (I don't want to repeat `$(date +'%Y.%m.%d-%H.%M.%S')` line):

```
env:
    NOW: 2022.07.06-21.56.48
    LINUX_ARM_64_NAME: linux-arm64_2022.07.06-21.56.48
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Environment variables are only available in steps after the one they're set in ([docs](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/environment-variables#passing-values-between-steps-and-jobs-in-a-workflow)).

You can either use separate steps:

```yaml
    - run: echo "NOW=$(date +'%Y.%m.%d-%H.%M.%S')" >> "$GITHUB_ENV"
    - run: echo "LINUX_ARM_64_NAME=linux-arm64_${{ env.NOW }}" >> "$GITHUB_ENV"
```

or you can use a temporary variable:

```yaml
    - name: BEFORE Set env variables
      run: |
        NOW=$(date +'%Y.%m.%d-%H.%M.%S')
        echo "NOW=$NOW" >> "$GITHUB_ENV"
        echo "LINUX_ARM_64_NAME=linux-arm64_$NOW" >> "$GITHUB_ENV"
```